# How to store an SSL/TLS certificate and its private key in AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl

I have an SSL/TLS certificate and its private key, I need to include this certificate when making http calls to an API. Both my application and the API are not on AWS.

I do not want to store the certificate or its private key on the application code base.

How can I store the certificate and the private key in AWS so that I retrieve them during the startup of my application, then configure my http client with the certificate and then make https calls to the external API?

Comment: If your application is not in AWS, you have another problem of how you access AWS. You'll need to authenticate to AWS to retrieve your secret, which may require you to store the AWS access keys somewhere, unless you have some kind of identity federation setup. But if you're able to securely store your AWS keys somewhere, you might as well store your other secrets in that manner as well... It would probably be worth knowing what platform your application _is_ running on, if any.

Comment: @sytech Yes, I have access to AWS and I am storing the AWS keys in environment variables. The application in deployed on K8 cluster. I want to use AWS to store the certificate and it's key.

Answer (score 1):

The standard options to store secrets in AWS are Secrets Manager and Parameter Store. Secrets Manager is more costly than Parameter Store, but has the option to auto-rotate the encryption.